# How do sort in mongo based on objects in url query string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express

```
I want to sort a mongo collection on base of following query in URL string from a node application.

http://localhost:5000/v1/bid/sort_bid?sort={"_id": -1,"enquiry_no": 1}

how do I pass an object in following code?

const getSortedBidList = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
let { sort } = req?.query;
    console.log('Query String', sort);
    let object = new Object();
    object[sort] === 1 ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';

let result = await Bid
        .find({})
        .sort(object)
        .limit(limit)
        .skip(offset);
```

}
In the sort method I am passing object of query string, but it didn't work.
Please help to sort this out.
Thank You

Comment: Try passing two separate parameters: `?sort_dir=asc&sort_field=some_key&limit=100`

Comment: parameters will be dynamic more than two parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
http://localhost:5000/v1/bid/sort_bid?sort[_id]=-1&sort[enquiry_no]=1
```

Learn more about how express parses query strings from [here](https://evanhahn.com/gotchas-with-express-query-parsing-and-how-to-avoid-them/).

I recommend that you use [npm `qs` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) to parse the objects on your frontend into query strings programatically:

```js
import qs from 'qs';

async function sendRequestToBackend(queryAsObject) {
  const stringifiedQuery = qs.stringify(queryAsObject);
  await sendRequest(`http://localhost:5000/v1/bid/sort_bid?${stringifiedQuery}`)
}
```

Comment: what in the case if coming parameters are more than two and dynamic

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how to do that dynamically.

Comment: @Alok007 please consider selecting this as the correct answer if it helped you.